# Is there a way to classify `/` divide operator image using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I am working on a project for solving basic maths handwritten questions with only machine learning models such as SVM, KNN or RFC.

SVM classifier gives the best accuracy on my dataset so I used it for the project. But I am unable to make it work for the '/' operator as the model confuses it with '7', '1', or 'X'.
The other 2 are even performing even worse.

What can I do to overcome this?

Is this doable with any machine learning model or is deep learning/Neural networks the only way for me?

Comment: Since this is a general machine learning question, and not a question about code (which this site is for - getting help with your code), I suggest seeing if you can find a more appropriate StackExchange site to ask this on, from this list of ML-focused sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms